# How do I use a List<T> to reference a Dictionary values?

Tags: c#

I'd like to have `List<MyObject> myList` reference Dictionary myDic values...I've tried

```
myList = myDic.Values.ToList()
```

but this seems to only copy the dictionary values. I need the list to reference the dictionary so any modifications (add, delete, update) made to myDic will be reflected in myList.

Comment: You already have a dictionary - if you need both keys and values, why try to transform it to a `List`?

Comment: because the list is actually an asynchronous bindinglist that i wrote which is bound to a datagridview. i'd like to perform data modifications on the dictionary because of the lookup speed and have the results reflected in my bindinglist which is bound to my grid

Answer (score 5):

This is not really possible.  `myDic.Values` is an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` that will enumerate the values in the dictionary.  By calling `.ToList()` on it you are *explicitly* requesting that a copy be made.  If you omit this call then you will have an enumerable that you can use instead, but of course you will be unable to index it or alter it directly.

Consider directly using the `IEnumerable<MyObject>` retrieved from `myDic.Values` instead -- what makes you think you need a `List<MyObject>`?

Comment: because the list is actually an asynchronous bindinglist that i wrote which is bound to a datagridview. i'd like to perform data modifications on the dictionary because of the lookup speed and have the results reflected in my bindinglist which is bound to my grid

Comment: Well, `BindingList<T>` sends out an event when it is modified so that views bound to that list can update themselves.  `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not have any such event.  In order to get this to work the way you want, you will probably have to write your own `BindingDictionary<TKey, TValue>` class that delegates storage to a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and raises the appropriate events whenever it is changed.

Comment: i'm taking a MAJOR performance hit when i have to iterate through the list to located items to modify or remove

Comment: Then writing your own bindable class is probably the way to go.

Comment: correct...i understand that the binding list sends out notifications but the user on the front end is also modifying the grid and in doing so needs to know the location of the item in the bindinglist and i have to search the list to locate the item and sometimes there are 1000's of items in the list

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could use an ObservableDictionary instead of your list implementation
having the goodies of both worlds: [which can be found here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx)

If you need a list AND a dictionary and need to synchronize both of them without the drawback of having a fresh copy each time the dictionary changes, why wouldn't you write a class for that?

Here an short example, which is probably not suitable for threading issues:

```
public class DictRefList
{
    private Dictionary<int, SomeRefClass> dict;
    private List<SomeRefClass> list; // your list implementation here

    public void DictRefList()
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<int, SomeRefClass>();
        list = new List<SomeRefClass>;
    }

    public void Add(int key, SomeRefClass val)
    { 
        dict.Add(key, val);
        list.Add(val);
    }

    public void Delete(int key, SomeRefClass val)
    {
        dict.Remove(key);
        list.Remove(val);
    }

    public void Update(int key, SomeRefClass val)
    {
        dict[key] = val;
        list.Add(val); // do what is necessary to keep it valid and have no duplicate value
    }
}
```

Comment: THANKS Mare!!! that's a good idea! i'm just an entry level dev so i'm still learning to think outside the box! i'm going to give that some thought and see where it goes. looks like it might be what i'm looking for. at least it will probably keep my supervisor off my my a** for a days lol!

Comment: i just see, the complete implementation can be obtained here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx and if you like this idea, feel free to upvote / accept it ;)

Comment: this isn't going to cut it because the list collection is using a linear search which takes too long to locate the object for removal. is there no way possible to have my List simply reference my Dictionary?